# Data modeling for a game - relation map to village and empty location

Tags: database, postgresql

I am working on a browser game. I have a map table that contains a list of positions:

```
CREATE TABLE map (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    x_pos integer NOT NULL,
    y_pos integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE (x_pos, y_pos)
);
```

A position can either be empty or used by a village. This is my villages tables. Note that each village must be located a position.

```
CREATE TABLE villages (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    population INT4 NOT NULL,
    owner_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES users(id),
);
```

There is one missing information missing in my current data model: check when a map location is free and if not, what is the village based in the location.

I was thinking to create a third table, a link table. However, it is mostly use to many-to-many relationship which is not my case.

```
 CREATE TABLE map_to_villages (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    location_id INT NOT NULL,
    village_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (location_id) REFERENCES map(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (village_id) REFERENCES villages(id)
);
```

The issue with a third table, is when I am looking for empty locations, I will have to look-up at the entire `map_to_villages` table and check if the `location_id` is present in this table.

Following Asa advice, update:

**map table (no changes):**

```
CREATE TABLE map (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    x_pos integer NOT NULL,
    y_pos integer NOT NULL,
    is_available BOOL NOT NULL, \* new column - TRUE is location is available *\
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    UNIQUE (x_pos, y_pos),
);
```

**villages table (added 1 column, location_id):**

```
CREATE TABLE villages (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    population INT4 NOT NULL,
    owner_id INT NOT NULL,
    location_id INT NOT NULL,  \* location where the village is located *\
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (location_id) REFERENCES map(id), \* new FK *\
);
```

However, in this scenario, I do have one issue, on my `villages` table, I could have multiple row with the same `located_id`, however we can only have 1 village per location.

Comment: Can you not use a located_on field in the villages table that is a foreign key to the map id column?

Comment: Yes, but what is the location is available (no village in this location), should this FK be NULL in that case?

Comment: When a new user register to the game, I need to select all available locations, the new user will select a spot, then this selected spot will become unavailable because this new_user new village is located in this spot

Comment: I think you have it backwards. A village will have a location - it cant be in the air. To find positions that are available you would check what ids in the map are not part of the located on column in the villages table

Comment: Yes correct, every villages have a location but not every location have a village. I think I may follow your suggestions

Comment: I just implemented your solution --> added located_on field in the villages tables. located_on column is not unique, so I could add 2 villages at the same position which should be not possible. I could add a UNIQUE constraint. But I am not even sure I need 2 separates tables in this case

Comment: Which 2 separate tables are you referring to? And yeah you should add a unique constraint

Comment: Ok, i updates my post and added the changes at the end.